# Self Contained .NET Core console app as a service in Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, service

I am creating a simple console application in .NET Core that needs to run as a service on Linux

The application is compiled with the following command:

> dotnet publish -c release -r linux-x64 --self-contained

And then run it without problem from the terminal with:

> cd publish
>
> ./MyAppName

Now I am trying to register it as a service by making its definition file as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo Bar Service
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/Desktop/publish
ExecStart=./home/Desktop/publish/MyAppName
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-postservice
User=myuser
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then register the service with

> sudo systemctl enable myappname.service

but when I check the status it gives me the following error

Unit myappname.service has a bad unit file setting.

Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ./home/Desktop/publish/MyAppName

Unit configuration has a faltal error, unit will not be started

If there is a solution where I don't have to install dotnet I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your working directory to

```
/home/Desktop/publish
```

Then you're doing

```
ExecStart=./home/Desktop/publish/MyAppName
```

Which means the command being run would be

```
/home/Desktop/publish/home/Desktop/publish/MyAppName
```

Take out the `./home/Desktop/publish`  on your `ExecStart` portion of the config and it should work.

Alternatively, drop the WorkingDirectory config and just give an absolute path to your executable like `/home/Desktop/publish/MyAppName` (notice it doesn't start with `./` and instead is just `/`.